# Java based JSON manipulations

Tags: java, json, xpath, jsonpath

Is anyone aware of a JSON-XPath style library that allows data manipulation; update, delete, create, etc...

```
JsonPath.write(json, "$.store.book[*].author", value);
```

I've looked into the following, but none allow altering the content.

[JPath](http://code.google.com/p/json-path/)

[JSONQuery](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/16/jsonquery-data-querying-beyond-jsonpath/)

[JSONiJ](http://projects.plural.cc/projects/jsonij/wiki/JPath)

Comment: This implementation of JsonPath for Java seems fine: https://github.com/nebhale/JsonPath

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy Can you reply as an answer and show how this implementation (com.nebhale.jsonpath) has modification/write capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) (im using 2.2.0) now allows the manipulation of JSON data. e.g.

```
    String jsonData = "{\"drink\":\"juice\"}";
    JsonPath.parse(jsonData).set("$.drink", "beer").jsonString();
```

results in `{"drink":"beer"}`

Answer (score 0):

JSON was not meant to be a database.

If you want to store your data in the JSON format;

- Read the JSON records into your Java application and create data objects.
- Modify the data objects in the Java application.
- When the application closes, write the JSON records back out.

You'd be better off using an actual database, relational or NoSQL, to store your data, and write JSON records when they're needed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this library I developped to be able to use XML libraries to manipulate JSON: https://github.com/bhabegger/json-n-xml/

It parses JSON to a DOM structure which you can manipulate with standard XML tools and then allows you to serialize back to json.

(JSON may not be meant to be a database but you do have occasions where you just want simple modifications.)

Hope it helps.